# Django How can we generate app wise log with app name directory and todaydate.log file

Tags: python, django

Django: How can we generate app wise log in with app name directory 
    I need to generate app wise log.Ex. 
    1: var/app1/todaydate.log
    2: var/app2/todaydate.log

Comment: Look at the logging module. You can configure it to name log files by date and you can use app name as part of the log file name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import os
import datetime

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
]

MY_APPS = [
    'accounts'
]

INSTALLED_APPS += MY_APPS

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(message)s'
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
    },
    'loggers': {
    }
}

MY_LOGGERS = {}
MY_HANDLERS = {}
for app in MY_APPS:
    directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)) + "/var/log/" + app + "/"
    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.makedirs(directory)

    MY_HANDLERS[app] = {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
        'filename': directory + '/' + str(datetime.date.today()) + '.log',
        'maxBytes': 1024*1024*5,
        'backupCount': 5,
        'formatter': 'verbose'
    }

    MY_LOGGERS[app] = {
        'handlers': [app],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': True,
    }
LOGGING['handlers'].update(MY_HANDLERS)
LOGGING['loggers'].update(MY_LOGGERS)
```